# Cannot save screenshot to file

Tags: screen-capture

At some point in history I made some settings change somewhere to save screenshots to the clipboard instead of the default Desktop location. However, I did this *somewhere else* than this place:

[image]

I still most often want to use the clipboard, for instance when posting this question :)

My problem is that both with or without control modifier, they're always saved to clipboard. I think this is because I didn't use this setting here but something else that interferes/overrides. I currently have no way to store a screenshot without going through the hassle of creating a new file in preview to paste into… Any tips highly appreciated!

---- Update to clarify:

I have tried all the normal screencapture settings and currently have:

```
defaults read com.apple.screencapture
{
    location = "/Users/viktor/screenshots";
    type = png;
}
```

However, there is still no way OSX ever produces any files, just clipboard. This is due to the fact that I made some more obscure change some time back that was not as simple as changing the shortcut like above or these plist settings that seem to be common now. What I need help with is finding out what that was to be able to restore. It was probably 5 years or so and my guess is that the shortcut settings for this didn't even exist at the time, therefore leaving me to use something else that now overrides this…

Comment: Here are the defaults - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152889/osx-screenshot-app-cant-change-screenshot-file-format - possible delete the defaults key or all defaults? [(Or this)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/267544/)

Comment: If you are confused about getting so much of details and don't wanna spend time figuring out what you want, here's one more link: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/238073/screenshot-save-destination?rq=1

Answer (score -1):

This link here should help you with what you want right now:
https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/change-macs-default-screenshot-directory

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Vighnesh - this is a good example of what we call a link only answer. Please ask a question on [meta] if you don’t understand why we love citations like you made, but require that the bulk of the answer be posted here. The point is to open source and contribute original knowledge here - not be a list of links.

Comment: Also - when you answer what may be a repeat question, consider doing a search here and voting to close as dupliacate rather than repeat the same answer - looking at the related section to the right - there are about a dozen potential duplicates.

Comment: As far as duplicates are concerned I totally agree but, link the only answer is something I would like to discuss with you. First of all, if anything is already explained in a fair manner, why copy-paste them here instead give a link here and rest follows. @bmike

Comment: I'll await your question on [meta]

Comment: Because the link may change or may not exist at all in the future. So by adding either other information or copying and pasting you make sure the answer stays relevant. | @bmike